# Strange "Error." that shows up after every commit

Tags: git

So I am trying to figure out why a strange error message gets posted after every commit.

```
RJ:zed-clone/ (master✗) $ gitcm 'test commit'
Taking capture into ~/.gitshots/1437266644.jpg!
[master f3f5788] change
 1 file changed, 3 insertions(+)
RJ:fazed-clone/ (master) $ Error. <<<< THIS

RJ:zed-clone/ (master) $
```

So far, there is no error that I can see, but I am unsure how to correct this from happening.

Comment: Just a guess, but this might be coming from your shell prompt (`$PS1`).

Comment: Take a look at `.git/hooks/post-commit` in your project's root

Comment: RJ:fazed-clone/ (master) $ echo $PS1                                                      [20:44:12]
%{$fg[$NCOLOR]%}%B%n%b%{$reset_color%}:%{$fg[blue]%}%B%c/%b%{$reset_color%} $(git_prompt_info)%(!.#.$)

Comment: The problem seems to be in any repo

Comment: Yeah, there's a call to an external command/function in there (`git_prompt_info`), which could theoretically produce error output.

Comment: post-commit says 

#!/usr/bin/env ruby
file="~/.gitshots/#{Time.now.to_i}.jpg"
unless File.directory?(File.expand_path("../../rebase-merge", __FILE__))
  puts "Taking capture into #{file}!"
  system "imagesnap -q -w 3 #{file} &"
end
exit 0

Comment: well this gets put in on every new repo. How do I get rid fo it?

Comment: Found out what it was. The .gitshots takes a selfie every commit. that should be interesting.  thanks any way. Didnt even know that you could have pre- and post git instructions.

Comment: @R.J.Robinson Maybe post the part about the selfie post-commit function as an answer to this question and accept it. If other people run into a similar issue, they can refer to your answer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error was due to a missing directory in my root path, and has since been correcte.d